# Sticky Navbar issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am having some issue in navbar but unable to find the error.I have made the navbar transparent but unable to make it sticky.  If you suggest me then that would be really good for me.

This is my Navbar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse-blue navbar">
<!--<div class="navbar navbar-inverse-blue navbar-fixed-top">-->
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="navigation">
         <nav id="colorNav">
           <ul>
            <li class="green">
                <a href="#" class="icon-home"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
           </ul>
         </nav>
       </div>
       <a class="brand" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="logo"></a>
       <div class="pull-right">
        <nav class="navbar nav_bottom" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header nav_2">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-toggle1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-megadropdown-tabs">Menu
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
       </div> 
       <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-megadropdown-tabs">


            <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav nav_1',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
        );
    ?>
         </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
       </div> <!-- end pull-right -->
      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div> <!-- end container -->
  </div> <!-- end navbar-inner -->
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.navbar-inverse-blue .navbar-inner {
  padding: 7px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: none;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  height: 70px; 
  z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

This is my Script

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                 $('navbar').addClass('fixed');
             }
             else {
                 $('navbar').removeClass('fixed');
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Dipankar Das, 
You forgot to put a dot on your class navbar. See code below.

From

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                 $('navbar').addClass('fixed');
             }
             else {
                 $('navbar').removeClass('fixed');
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
             if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                 $('.navbar').addClass('fixed');
             }
             else {
                 $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed');
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ya it's working but my navbar menu items are coming vertically instead of horizontally. any solution for that ?

Comment: I think it is more on css part that causes the vertical position of the menu items.